# Nested Single file Component problem with Grid component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I am trying to build a grid component in vue. And then use this to set up a sortable and searchable chart. I need to use Single File Component. I also used vue-router. Here in below are my two .vue files. I can only see the search bar in my localhost. And there are several errors showed up in the console. The original Fiddle of separate files https://jsfiddle.net/Tertia/vbyon64p/6/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vbyon64p

This is my `chart.vue`

```
<template>
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid></demo-grid>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import DemoGrid from "./grid";

export default {
  
  name :'chart',
   components: {DemoGrid},

  props: {
    heroes: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders,
       searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHeroes: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var heroes = this.heroes
      if (filterKey) {
        heroes = heroes.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        heroes = heroes.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return heroes
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style >
```

This is my `grid.vue`, a template

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredHeroes">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is the ideal look of the grid. It is sortable and searchable.
[image: The ideal output]

And here are my errors.

[image: Here are my errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your code in all the wrong places. Most likely due to the lack of understanding of the [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) concept and [Component Basics](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Here's me literally copy and pasting code from the original fiddle into their respective components.

Your `chart.vue` should look like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="demo">
    <form id="search">
      Search
      <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
    </form>
    <demo-grid :heroes="gridData" :columns="gridColumns" :filter-key="searchQuery"></demo-grid>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DemoGrid from "./grid.vue";
export default {
  name: "Chart",
  components: {
    DemoGrid
  },
  data() {
    return {
      searchQuery: "",
      gridColumns: ["name", "power"],
      gridData: [
        { name: "Chuck Norris", power: Infinity },
        { name: "Bruce Lee", power: 9000 },
        { name: "Jackie Chan", power: 7000 },
        { name: "Jet Li", power: 8000 }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Your `grid.vue` should look like this:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
          v-for="(key, index) in columns"
          :key="index"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
        >
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(entry, index) in filteredHeroes" :key="index">
        <td v-for="(key, index) in columns" :key="index">{{ entry[key] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DemoGrid",
  props: {
    heroes: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function() {
    const sortOrders = {};
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1;
    });
    return {
      sortKey: "",
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHeroes() {
      const sortKey = this.sortKey;
      const filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase();
      const order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1;
      let heroes = this.heroes;
      if (filterKey) {
        heroes = heroes.filter(function(row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function(key) {
            return (
              String(row[key])
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(filterKey) > -1
            );
          });
        });
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        heroes = heroes.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey];
          b = b[sortKey];
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order;
        });
      }
      return heroes;
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize(str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy(key) {
      this.sortKey = key;
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
th,
td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
th.active {
  color: #fff;
}
th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}
.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}
.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
</style>
```

Assuming both components are in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have this idea of splitting code into two .vue files. But I get confused on how to put the two data function merged together somehow. And it turns out they are supposed to be separated in two file like the `html` part does. It's all very clear right now.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your components!